# How to group a employees by using their date of joining on dictionary in swift4

Tags: swift

How to group a employees by using their date of joining on dictionary in Swift 4.

I have tried many format but it is't working.
I have tried this using basic Objective-C and did know how to express it using Swift 4.

```
var grooupedByDate = (employees.map({$0["DateOfJoin"] == "1-3-2018"}))
for grooupedByDate in grooupedByDate {
    print(grooupedByDate)
}
```

Comment: Is `DateOfJoin` a `String` date representation in the format "d-M-yyyy" or is it an actual `Date` object?

Comment: yes it is a string representation in the form of "dd-MM-yyyy"